# How can I add a button to every row of custom column?

Tags: 8, views, hooks

I have created a custom column in the content listing section using `hook_views_data()`. I want to add a button to the every row of that custom column. Can anyone help me with this issue?

```php
function sortd_views_data() {
  $data['node_field_data']['SortdAction'] = [
    'title' => t('Sortd Action'),
    'help' => t('Manual Sync/Unsync articles.'),
    'field' => [
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'id' => 'numeric',
    ],
    'sort' => [
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ],
    'filter' => [
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
    ],
    'argument' => [
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
    ],
  ];
  
  return $data;  
}
```

The 0 show for every row needs to be replaced with the button.

> [image: screenshot]

I tried to solve the problem using the following code.

```php
function sortd_preprocess_views_view_table(&$variables) {
  drupal_set_message($variables['rows']);
  if ($variables['view']->id() == 'content') {
    foreach ($variables['rows'] as &$row) {
      $row['SortdAction'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Sortd'),
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to print `$variables['row']`, it shows me the correct data in that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In /admin/structure/views/view/YOUR_VIEW_ID, add a new field (*Custom text*)
2. In your hook, use the following code

   ```php
   function sortd_preprocess_views_view_field(&$vars){
     if ($vars['view']->id() == 'YOUR_VIEW_ID') {
       if ($vars['field']->field == 'nothing') {
         $vars['output'] = [
           '#markup' => "<div class='dropbutton-wrapper dropbutton-multiple'><div><ul class='dropbutton'><li class='edit dropbutton-action'></li></ul></div></div>",
         ]
       }
     }  
   }
   ```
3. Clear the cache